# How would I write new algorithm that uses the fact that A and B are sorted to achieve better run-time complexity than this?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

```
Algorithm bar(A,n,B,m)
  Input: arrays of integers, A of length n and B of length m
  Output: true or false

for i := 0 to n-1
    for j := 0 to m-1
        if A[i] == B[j]
            return true
        endif
    endfor
endfor

return false
```

Comment: See merge sort's merging procedure.

Comment: Please describe what this algorithm `bar()` does? Does it returns true if there is any common element in A and B?

Comment: The algorithm compares the items in each array to find a match with the elements in B and A. Yeah, It returns true when theres a match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can traverse both arrays from start to end simultaneously, proceeding either on `B` or `A`, depending upon which element is smaller (assuming the arrays are sorted ascendingly):

```
def bar(A, n, B, m):
    x = 0
    y = 0

    while x < n and y < m:
        if A[x] < B[y]:
            x++
        elif A[x] > B[y]:
            y++
        else:
            return True

    return False
```

Worst-case runtime would be `O(n + m)` - traverse both arrays once without finding a matching pair.

Comment: What do you reckon would be the new run-time complexity would be?

Comment: `O(n + m)` worst-case.